# Spring validation field type

Tags: spring, rest, validation, spring-mvc

I'm writing REST service in Spring, and I would like to have some form validation.
Let's say, that my POJO class has Integer field - age. How to check, if value that came with request is really an Integer? Is there any annotation for that, or should I write some logic for that? I would like to add some comment if validation won't pass in same style like e.g. @NotNull(message = "Product Number cannot be empty.")

Comment: Did you google the problem at all? In general what you search is the @Valid annotation

Comment: Yes, i annotated my model with @Valid, but that's not the problem. I would like to have custom error message if type of specified field in that model is invalid.

Comment: There is not the concept of real integer. If the jackson can marshall it,than its fine. If you want to limit the range of valid values use (at)Min and (at)Max

Comment: I think you dont understand my question. I asked, if value that came is realy a Integer. Someone could just send {"age": "asd"} instead of correct value which is a number.

Comment: And than it most likely end up something like JsonMappingException that you could catch with a spring exception handler. Validation kicks in after deserialization.